# How to have HibernateUtil statically initialized before servlet is called?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I want a java servlet to access a database via hibernate in the doGet method and I created the HibernateUtil class to call buildSessionFactory in a static context

When testing, I get an error "tomcat failed to start", apparently (?) because openSession in the doGet method is called before the buildSessionFactory call in the HibernateUtil class.

How do I ensure that the HibernateUtil class gets statically initialied before the doGet method in the servlet?

Here is the class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration()
                .configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I'm calling from the doGet() method like this:

```
Session session = null;
try {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    // ...
}
```

Stack trace follows:

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 10, 2014 12:58:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Feb 10, 2014 12:58:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/dbwebtest]]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/dbwebtest]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:142)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
  ... 21 more
```

Comment: Your interpretation of the error is incorrect. Show us the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: It looks like the hibernate jar file (or one of its dependencies) is not in the webapp's classpath, i.e. in WEB-INF/lib: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException`

Comment: That's indeed the case; if you submit that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the hibernate jar file (or one of its dependencies) is not in the webapp's classpath, i.e. in WEB-INF/lib:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Servlet Filter to create the SessionFactory and open/close sessions.  Hibernate calls this the Open-Session-In-View pattern and implementation is described here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView?_sscc=t